# Do I need to cancel StreamSubscriptions?

Tags: events, memory-leaks, stream, dart

I understand that every time I listen for an event, a new StreamSubscription object is created

```
element.onMouseMove.listen
```

My question is: when will be this StreamSubscription object freed from the memory? Will it linger in there until I call it's *cancel()* method? Or is it enough to remove the element/object the StreamSubscription is listening to?
When exactly do I have to worry about memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the element is removed from the DOM and no 'active' variable has a reference to this element the garbage collector will release the memory of the element and the StreamSubscription.
With 'active' I'm talking about a variable that is held by a class that can't be garbage collected because the class itself is referenced.

If the element is kept in the DOM for a long time but the listeners come and go you should subscribe and unsubscribe when a listener is no longer interested in events.

subscribe:

```dart
StreamSubscription _moveSubscr = element.onMouseMove.listen(moveHandler);
```

unsubscribe

```dart
if(_moveSubscr != null) _moveSubscr.cancel;
```

Comment: Cool! I take it that it's the same with every object that is capable of listening to events, not just the DOM elements, right?

Comment: Yep, subscribing to events is listening to streams. Streams are used for notifying subscribers everywhere in Dart.